# How to use SqlBulkCopy to prevent duplicates insert?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sqlbulkcopy

I am going to use SqlBulkCopy, but I need to prevent duplicates insert. What is the best way to do it? Have I do check existence for each item before make execute WriteToServer command?

Comment: What Magnus gave is good enough if you want to remove duplicates from the rows available in db. But are you asking for some general practices in finding the duplicates in the data set you are inserting.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to add a unique index onto the table you are inserting the data into. This will prevent any duplicate entries from being added to the table.

This also prevents you from having to potentially load too much data into memory and creating other problems for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you do not really specify what is your source. If it is a flat file you could SqlBulkCopy into a staging table and afterwards use a `insert into` sql statement that filters out the duplicates.